# How to change the position of header columns of excel file using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, xlsx, exceljs, json2xls

I have a dynamic JSON data fro which I am creating a Excel file using `jsno2xls` library nut here the resulting excel file header are like `Year`,`DOB`,`Name` and `Age` and I want excel data in this format `Name`,`Age`,`DOB` and `Year`.Is there any way I can perform this action and get data in desired format.

Below is what I am doing to create Excel sheet.

```
const parsedData = [{},....,{}];
const xls = json2xls(parsedData);
fs.writeFileSync('datasheet.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
```

Here in above code `parsedData` is coming from database which can have any number of fields in JSON object.

But in resulting Excel file I always want `Name` and `Age` column at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing `options` object, where you set `fields` property to an array of fields you want to export, which will also export them in that order:

```
const xls = json2xls(parsedData, {
    fields: ['Name', 'Age', 'DOB', 'Year']
});
```

If keys don't correspond (not case sensitive), then try transforming the data, where you'll create a new object whose keys correspond to those you want in the xlsx file:

```
const parsedData = [{
    dob: "dob",
    name: 'bar',
    age: 'moo',
    year: new Date()
}];    

const transformedJson = parsedData.map(obj => {

    const newObject = {};

    newObject['D O B'] = obj['dob'];
    newObject['Name'] = obj['name'];
    newObject['Age'] = obj['age'];
    newObject['Year'] = obj['year'];

    return newObject;

});   
 
var xls = json2xls(transformedJson, {
    fields: ['Name', 'Age', 'D O B', 'Year']
});

fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
```

Comment: I have white spaces in `D O B` like this when I am writing this inside `fields`  array as per you solution with white spaces then this `D O B` column is coming empty in excel file.

Comment: is the order of columns respected? if so, then that's another question. can you include an example of json, it's hard to say..

Comment: how does the `D O B` look like in JSON? try `fields: {'D O B':'string'}`

Comment: No columns order is respected and when I put 'D O B' its showing this particular column empty.Its because json field was 'dob' but in excel sheet I want it to be 'D O B'.

Comment: alright, so your initial question about the order is answered. About the column names, try transforming the data then by creating new objects and setting the keys exactly as you want them in the file, try the updated code